# Cointreau on Passover

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, liquor-beer, selling-mechirat-chametz

Can those who do not rely on *heter mechira* (selling) for real *chametz* keep Cointreau over Passover? What is the origin of the alcohol in Cointreau? Does Cointreau contain grain alcohol from, e.g., wheat or barley?

[This website](https://www.alcoholprofessor.com/blog-posts/blog/2013/03/23/passover-triple-sec-brownies) seems to imply that Cointreau is even kosher for Passover, but I have been unable to find any corroborating source for this assertion from a certifying authority or from the [Cointreau website](https://www.cointreau.com/us/en/?gate=show).

Comment: This website seems to imply it's made from sugar beets(?): https://theculturetrip.com/north-america/usa/articles/how-to-drink-better-during-passover/

Comment: as does this: https://www.alcademics.com/2011/10/a-visit-to-the-cointreau-distillery-in-angers-france.html

Comment: It does appear to have been listed as kosher by the London Beth Din: https://www.kosher.org.uk/sites/default/files/2016%20March_0.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Cointreau is French so let's ask the French .... the Consistoire (France's central Jewish authority)'s [website](https://www.consistoire.org/produit/) says the regular Cointreau is Kosher and it has been on the [kosher product list](http://www.consistoire.org/pdf/Produits_Selectionnes_2018_2019L.pdf) for a long time.

I consulted different sites (e.g., [here](https://fr.quora.com/Quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-Cointreau-et-Grand-Marnier) and [here](https://www.forums.supertoinette.com/recettes-30256-quelle-difference-grand-marnier-et-cointreau)) who all mention the alcohol in Cointreau is from sugar beets.

Regarding your specific question R Avraham Taieb [writes](https://www.torah-box.com/question/cointreau-hamets-gamour_10882.html) (on Torah-box, a key French-speaking Jewish site) Cointreau **is not *hametz gamur*** even if some *hametz* components might be added to it. It should therefore be sold for Pesach and can be sold by someone who doesn't sell real *hametz*.

PS. be careful **not** to confuse regular Cointreau with [Cointreau Noir](https://www.cointreau.com/fr/fr/la-collection-cointreau/cointreau-noir) which is a mix with Cognac, same for Grand Marnier which also tastes of orange but is cognac-based. Both are not kosher.